# Optimized 3D rendering using dots and/or line segments of different sizes in Scratch

Tags: rendering, 3d, computational-geometry

I'm developing a 3D rendering engine in Scratch, which is a block-based visual programming language. It does not have any support for bitmap rendering, but there is a "pen" plugin that lets you draw lines and dots on the screen programmatically. The main bottleneck seems to be the speed that the pen tool can draw stuff.

Existing 3D rendering engines made with Scratch all seem to use some kind of optimized triangle drawing algorithm. The algorithm works by essentially drawing a large dot in the middle of the triangle and then drawing progressively smaller dots around it to minimize drawing operations. This algorithm is also capable of basic shading and transparency.

My 3D engine does not necessarily need the capability to handle dynamically-moving objects. It would be nice if it had simple texture support. I'm currently planning on using a triangle drawing algorithm combined with binary space partitioning for fast Z-ordering and the ability to handle large scenes.

What would be the best approach to rendering 3D geometry with these limitations? Should I design my rendering engine to be based on drawing triangles, or should I take another approach entirely?

Bonus points if the method allows for adaptive levels of detail.